# Would my fingerprints still be on file from a 2013 application?

Tags: visas, schengen, applications, czech-republic, ghanaian-citizens

I am from Ghana. I have been refused for a Poland  schengen visa in Nigeria since 2013 up to now. I am now applying for a Czech schengen visa at Saudi Arabia. Do they stiil have my fingerprints since 2013?

Comment: To try to give a better answer, could you explain why you think it matters whether or not 'they' do still have your fingerprints on file?

Comment: Ohk.since 2013 up to date am now applying for a schengen visa again 2019.

Comment: Ok, sure - we get that, but why does it matter if they still have your fingerprints? If they do - then what? If they don't, what changes?

Comment: Is it true that fingerprints last in the system for 5yrs.

Comment: If my fingerprints is there, now I can't remember my refused queries

Answer (score 6):

We get a lot of questions like this and it always feels like the underlying question is "I've been rejected for visas in the past and I'd like to apply again now. If I can get away with it, lying about my past would increase my chance of getting the visa. So, if I lie, will I get caught?"

You should always assume that they know your application history, and you should answer all questions on the application form honestly and truthfully. If you are found to have lied, your application will be refused, your visa will be revoked if it has been granted, and you will be banned from applying again for some amount of time.

It sounds like you've been refused a visa more than once. You're unlikely to get a visa unless you have fixed whatever things caused the rejection of your earlier applications.

Comment: I only apply one and I got refused.my issue is that,is it still my fingerprints data in the system since 2013 up to 2019. It 5 years now.

Comment: My answer stands. You should tell the truth on your application form and you should make sure that you've solved the problems that caused you to be rejected last time.

Comment: 5 yes now it well very difficult remember the queries. What shoild I do now?

Comment: @Kennedy Tell the truth. That’s not difficult is it? I am also from Ghana and the meaning of the truth is the same in Ghana as everywhere else. It doesn’t matter whether they have your fingerprint on file or not.

Answer (score 0):

Data is kept in the VIsa Information System (VIS) used by Schengen states for five years. This retention period starts from the expiry date of the issued visa, the date a negative decision is taken or the date a decision to modify an issued visa is taken. https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-information-system_en

Comment: Traveller brief me a little I don't understand ur answer well.thanks

Comment: Since I want apply again, now I can't remember exactly what the refusal was.what shd I do now

Comment: @Kennedy It’s quite straightforward. If the application form asks whether you’ve previously been denied a visa, answer ‘yes’. If it asks for details, answer that it was a visa for Poland in 2013 but you don’t remember the reason for the refusal.

Comment: Thank please can you please guide me this time for applying one again.your experience in this fields

Comment: @Kennedy What guide are you looking for? The application form is simple, fill out the truth. Also check the list of recommended supporting documents and add those.